# What's this plant that produces fruits or vegetables and have green to black leafs?

Tags: identification, vegetables, fruits

My parents have two of those plants in their backyard.  They forgot what it is. It produces fruits or vegetables. The leafs goes from green to almost black on the outside.  The flowers are purple.

[image: Global plant]
[image: Fruits or vegetables]

They would like to know what it is exactly.

Comment: It's not an eggplant or pepper. However, the flowers look like eggplant flowers, and the fruits kind of look like eggplants or peppers. The stem looks interesting. I would venture to say it's almost assuredly in the nightshade family, in the Solanum genus. The leaves do not look familiar at all; I've seen a lot of plants in the nightshade family. Is the fruit edible or toxic? What color is it when ripe? What does it look like when ripe? What do the seeds look like?

Comment: The odds are extremely high that the fruit is deadly. So, if you don't know that it's edible for sure, I don't recommend trying it to find out. Where did they get these plants?

Comment: @Shule They bought it, that's for sure.  I will ask them if they remember where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really know for sure, but the closest thing I've found appearance-wise is poroporo, AKA the [kangaroo apple](http://www.habitas.org.uk/gardenflora/solanum_laciniatum.htm) ([Solanum aviculare](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanum_aviculare), or Solanum laciniatum). There may be some subtle differences in appearance, though. It may also be the more poisonous large-flowered kangaroo apple (Solanum laciniatum Aiton).

The regular kangaroo apple is [edible only when dark orange](https://myfolia.com/plants/72771-kangaroo-apple-solanum-laciniatum).

Comment: I think you found it.  It looks really similar. I'm going to try to ask around in some shops to see if it's really that.  I wonder if the dark foliage is due to cold weather at nights. (8-10°C)